# MySQL: Empty string with wildcards do not return any results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a procedure that looks something below. 
It returns results only if the **_keyword** is set for some reason.
But if the **_keyword** is an empty string, it returns nothing.

★ _keyword is a dynamic variable to this procedure and not NULL

What could be the cause of this behavior?

```
set @cart_count := 0;
set @fav_count := 0;
set @access_count := 0;
set @i := 0;

set @orderCol := 'itemId';
set @offset := 1;
set @maxLimit := 30;
set @keyword := concat('%', _keyword, '%');
set @targetDate := '2018-01-05';

select
  t.item_id,
  t.item_title,
  t.item_url,
  t.item_status,
  t.cart_count,
  t.favourite_count,
  t.access_count,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.created_date) as created_date
from (
       select
         t1.item_id,
         t1.item_title,
         t1.item_url,
         t1.item_status,
         t1.created_date,
         @val1 := if(@item_id1=t1.item_id, t1.cart_count - @cart_count, t1.cart_count) as cart_count,
         @val1 := if(@item_id1=t1.item_id, t1.favourite_count - @fav_count, t1.favourite_count) as favourite_count,
         @val1 := if(@item_id1=t1.item_id, t1.access_count - @access_count, t1.access_count) as access_count,
         @cart_count := t1.cart_count,
         @fav_count := t1.favourite_count,
         @access_count := t1.access_count,
         @item_id1 := t1.item_id
       from some_table t1
       where date(t1.created_date) = @targetDate AND (t1.item_title like @keyword or t1.item_id like @keyword)
     ) t
where  (@i := @i+1) BETWEEN @offset and @maxLimit
       and t.cart_count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where/how you are setting the value of `_keyword`, but I propose that the empty string value you think you have is actually `NULL`.  Consider the following two queries:

```
select 'empty string matches' from dual where 'hello' like '%%';
select 'null matches' from dual where 'hello' like concat('%', NULL, '%');
```

### Demo

Only `empty string matches` will appear in the output.  The reason why `CONCAT('%', NULL, '%')` does not match anything is that `NULL` means unknown.  Hence, we cannot say in general that it does or does not match anything.

Comment: Actually I already tested it with `set @keyword := concat('%','', '%');`, but did not make any difference. The _keyword is alway a string(could be empty), but not NULL.

Comment: @d-_-b Then maybe the other portion of the `WHERE` clause is failing.  Check your logic, because AFAIK `LIKE '%%'` will return every record.  I will leave this up until you get an answer.

Comment: Only dynamic variable is only the **_keyword ** here and other parameters are made static purposely. If other parts of the `WHERE` clause are falling, the procedure should alway return nothing regardless of the _keyword, shouldn't it?

Comment: @d-_-b You need to give us a reproducible example here.  I can't reproduce the problem of `CONCAT('%', '', '%')` not returning every record.